# What fork size is 32mm (inside diameter on the frame) considered?

Tags: frames, fork, bike-fit, stem, build

Good day, I'm new to the whole bike building process, but I've finally decided to make the step and build a semi-nice bike.

I've bought a really nice aluminium frame 2nd hand, but its sizing has me stumped. The **inside diameter** of the front part of the frame (where the front fork goes in) is **~32mm**. I've been searching online (e.g. http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-headsets.html) for a couple of days, but I cannot understand what type of fork I should get.

Should I get an 1 1/8", 1.5" or some other type of fork?

**EDIT:** After some investigation, the bike frame is an Alpinestar Almega DX, the same as in this picture [image] I couldn't find any specs though :(

Here is what I measured, when I said it was ~32mms (apparently it's the headset, not the pipe itself). The other end is the same size. [image]

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of frame is it?  It would be unusual for the fork size to not be provided along with the frame.

Comment: It's a "26, MTB frame.

Comment: What I meant was, what make/model of frame is it?  Does it have a headset fitted?  Could you post a picture?

Comment: As mentioned, I bought it 2nd hand and it came as-is, with no other information and no stickers. There is a headset fitted.  I can upload a picture at a later time. In a better world, I would have some information about what brand of frame it is, I would contact the maker and ask what fork is appropriate.

However, since that is not the case, I'm asking if this size is something commonly seen or seen at all and under what name, since i'm a noob.

Comment: Does the headset have anything marked on it?

Comment: 32mm is an uncommon but not unheard of size, that's about 1-1/4", but you will need the upper and lower measurement of the head tube (where the fork goes) Where was this measurement taken from? Is the top of the head tube skinnier than the bottom?

Comment: Thanks Nate, I just reached the same conclusion. There is a weird 1-1/4" standard (yes, the top and the bottom are both the same size) and I've accidentally bought a frame with it. I was hoping that I didn't understand the standards but I guess I got a weird frame.

P.S. Would you please create an Answer so I can select it? I don't want to leave the question floating as unanswered.

Comment: 1 1/4" or 1 1/8" are measurements referring to the size of the steered on the fork, not the size of the hole in the frame. When you measure, are you measuring the inside diameter of the headset cup, or the raw frame? (You said a headset was fitted?)

Comment: Yes steer tube, idk what i was thinking. It was one of those days yesterday lol. But yeah you have a 1-1/4 headset so you should be able to find a fork to work without anything else being done. Check the bottom measurement of the headset too

Comment: The caliper reads 33.0 mm, which is the steerer diameter or crown race ID for 1 1/4" threaded. Some googling found out that Alpinestars indeed used 1 1/4" headsets. 

What I don't understand is the part you are measuring in the picture, it looks like crown race but that part should be on the fork, not fixed to the frame and the entire cup that should be mounted to frame is missing.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with this! I learned a great deal in the process :)

I've ordered some 1-1/4" to 1-1/8" headset reducer cups and will go from there (there aren't any 1-1/4" forks sold in my country). 

@ojs I'm not very familiar with the hedaset parts, but the part i've measured is the top and it looks like the cup itself is missing, but it's irrelevant since i'm going to put a new headset with all the bells and whistles :)

Please post your comments as Answers so I can give you some fake internet points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 32mm approximate head tube inside diameter, this is an 1 1/8" frame, assuming it is a standard headset design.

An 1 1/4" head tube would have approximately a 35mm inside diameter.

[image: Head tube sizing for traditional Headset]

Here is a [link to a PDF from Cane Creek detailing most other styles of headsets](http://www.canecreek.com/resources/products/headsets/technical-specifications/oe-head-tube-specification-guide.pdf) fitment for non-traditional options.

These have become very common also.